# Expand and simplify

Tags: quadratics

I've removed the brackets from the first equation in where it is 5a^2 + 2a - 5 and then multiplied 3 to the numbers inside the bracket. But I'm not sure what steps to take after that. (5a^2 + 2a - 5) + 3(2a + 2 - 2b^2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add similar expression.
$$5a^2+2a-5+6a+6-6b^2=5a^2-6b^2+8a+1$$